# Как правильно создать меню в PHP

Tags: php

Создал меню в отдельном файле "header.php"
На главной странице сайта "index.php", вызвал меню через **"include"**

В строении меню нет не одной строки **php кода.**
Меню у меня на чистом **html** и **css.**
У меня все это работает корректно.

*Вопрос такой:*
Вызывать в **PHP** тот файл, который 
не имеет не одной строки php кода)?
Это правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете делать меню какое угодно. Сегодня у вас там нет строк с `php` кодом, но завтра он может появиться. Вообще, структура меню планируется на этапе проектирования. Например:

```
<?php if($Admin): ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="/see">See</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php endif ?>
```

Выше указанный пример демонстрирует, то как завтра вам могут сказать, выводи всем только страницу `about`, а админам всё.

По поводу, что необходимо использовать `include` или `require` почитать [тут](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20include%20%D0%B8%20require&oq=%D0%B2%20%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83%20require%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0.11544j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: Благодарю за полезную информацию))) Вызывать в PHP тот файл, который не имеет не одной строки php кода, получается это не будет считаться ошибкой)?

Comment: @Black_Viper не будет

Comment: @Black_Viper просто это бессмысленно. Если я ответил на ваш вопрос, необходимо отметить его как ответ.

Comment: Я и не знаю как отметить ваш ответ((( Я тут новичек.